# inserting images in python using in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I'm just trying to insert a image in python using mysql and this is my code

```
import mysql.connector
import base64

conn = mysql.connector.Connect(user="root",passwd="solomon",host="localhost",db="binarymanipulation",port="3306")

cursor = conn.cursor();
with open('/home/solomon/Downloads/javapic.jpeg', 'rb') as image:
    imager = image.read()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,imager)")
conn.commit();
conn.close()
```

While running this code I'm getting the following error:

```
error/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/solomon/PycharmProjects/untitled/Helloworrld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/solomon/PycharmProjects/untitled/Helloworrld.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,imager)")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'imager' in 'field list'
```

Comment: It seems the "imager" not exists, post your show tables info may helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
import base64

conn = mysql.connector.Connect(user="root",passwd="solomon",host="localhost",db="binarymanipulation",port="3306")

cursor = conn.cursor();
with open('/home/solomon/Downloads/javapic.jpeg', 'rb') as image:
    imager = image.read()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,imager)")
conn.commit();
conn.close()
```

Because sql is not format, it is a  variable in Python, try to execute 
the sql :

```
INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,imager)
```

will get the same error , you can format it first may helps:

```
import mysql.connector
import base64

conn = mysql.connector.Connect(user="root",passwd="solomon",host="localhost",db="binarymanipulation",port="3306")

cursor = conn.cursor();
with open('/home/solomon/Downloads/javapic.jpeg', 'rb') as image:
    imager = image.read()

sql = "INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,%s)" % imager
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '???' at line 1